General Solutions to this Differential Equations $ y_{xx} + \frac{N-1}{x}y_x + e^y=0 \qquad x>0$
This is a second order differential equation with variable coefficients
\begin{equation}
   y_{xx} + \frac{N-1}{x}y_x + e^y=0 \qquad x>0
\end{equation}
for some $N$ such that $3\leq N \leq 9$.
I’ve been looking for some possible method to solve this problem. But I have not found anything that serves me for this case that has a exponential as an independent form.
I know it’s from the form $y'=f(x,y,y')$. But this case has no general solution.

Maple and Mathematica they won't be able to either.

I cannot find or come up with a solution but we can reduce it to a common first order equation. Let $y=z-2\log(x)$ and $\xi=\log(x)$ to arrive at the autonomous equation
\begin{align}
z''_{\xi\xi}+(N-2)z'_\xi+e^z+2(2-N)=0.
\end{align}
This can be reduced by one order via the transformation $z'_\xi=-(N-2)u(z)$ to
\begin{align}
uu'_z-u=\frac{1}{(N-2)^2}e^z+\frac{2}{N-2},
\end{align}
an Abel equation of the second kind in canonical form, as all nonlinear ODEs which can be reduced seem to..... The Handbook of Solutions to Ordinary Differential Equations by Polyanin and Zaitsev does not contain a solution for this, only for similar equations with different coefficients.

Yes, my first search was in that manual, but I didn't find anything for my second order differential equations. From what you tell me, making a change to reduce your order either. Thank for responding.
